# mp4 Video Plays in Browser but no Media Player

Tags: browser, mp4, vlc

I have some MP4 videos I downloaded off X and saved, locally, that play fine in a web browser, but will not play in any media player.

They have size; they are not zero byte files. If I drag the file to chrome, brave or edge, they play, but they won't play in VLC or anything else. I have disconnected the internet and the videos still play fine, in a browser, so they can't be streaming from somewhere, somehow.

From exifTool

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 12.65
File Name                       : kTV9KVKVfi8yjORH.mp4
Directory                       : C:/Users/owner/Downloads
File Size                       : 12 MB
Zone Identifier                 : Exists
File Modification Date/Time     : 2023:09:13 10:20:05-05:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2023:09:13 10:20:05-05:00
File Creation Date/Time         : 2023:09:13 10:20:04-05:00
File Permissions                : -rw-rw-rw-
File Type                       : MP4
File Type Extension             : mp4
MIME Type                       : video/mp4
Major Brand                     : MP4 Base Media v5
Minor Version                   : 0.2.0
Compatible Brands               : iso6, mp41
Movie Header Version            : 0
Create Date                     : 0000:00:00 00:00:00
Modify Date                     : 0000:00:00 00:00:00
Time Scale                      : 480000
Duration                        : 0 s
Preferred Rate                  : 1
Preferred Volume                : 100.00%
Preview Time                    : 0 s
Preview Duration                : 0 s
Poster Time                     : 0 s
Selection Time                  : 0 s
Selection Duration              : 0 s
Current Time                    : 0 s
Next Track ID                   : 3
Track Header Version            : 0
Track Create Date               : 0000:00:00 00:00:00
Track Modify Date               : 0000:00:00 00:00:00
Track ID                        : 1
Track Duration                  : 0 s
Track Layer                     : 0
Track Volume                    : 0.00%
Image Width                     : 480
Image Height                    : 270
Graphics Mode                   : srcCopy
Op Color                        : 0 0 0
Compressor ID                   : avc1
Source Image Width              : 480
Source Image Height             : 270
X Resolution                    : 72
Y Resolution                    : 72
Bit Depth                       : 24
Pixel Aspect Ratio              : 1:1
Matrix Structure                : 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
Media Header Version            : 0
Media Create Date               : 0000:00:00 00:00:00
Media Modify Date               : 0000:00:00 00:00:00
Media Time Scale                : 480000
Media Duration                  : 0 s
Media Language Code             : und
Handler Type                    : Audio Track
Handler Description             : Twitter-vork muxer
Balance                         : 0
Audio Format                    : mp4a
Audio Channels                  : 2
Audio Bits Per Sample           : 16
Audio Sample Rate               : 48000
Movie Fragment Sequence         : 408
Media Data Size                 : 4895912
Media Data Offset               : 7291697
Image Size                      : 480x270
Megapixels                      : 0.130
Rotation                        : 0
```

Has anyone ever come across this?